# What is "offsetTimestamp"

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I have a lot of data in Flurry. Inside that, I can see many identical events ( as a json file) they only differ in there offsetTimeStamp.

I there anyone who can help like what is offsetTimeStamp ?

I tried to find many docs but could not get any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offsetTimestamp is the start time of the event relative to the session start time in milliseconds.

You can calculate the time the event occurred by summing the session time(t) and the offsetTimestamp(o).

t + o = Time the event occurred in milliseconds since the epoch